# How to edit background color (rgba) of a class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'd want to edit a background color of a class. In JavaScript i have a function which will happen after an audio file has ended. I want to include a script to that function which will change the background color of a class called "text1" to color "rgba(0,0,0,0)" which will equal in the background being transparent.

HTML:

```
<span class="text1">Some text</span>
```

script.js of the html

```
audio.onended=function(){ "insert here the background changing script" }
```

style.css of text1

```
.text1{ color: white; background: #000; }
```

I have tried `getElementByClassName` with no success and I can't change the class to id because it will brake other stuff of the html file.

Comment: I honestly didnt think of that. If you could provide a sample of the class change in javascript i would be thankfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an additional class instead of changing the class.

```
audio.onended = function() {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".text1")).forEach(el => el.classList.add("transparent"));
};
```

and then add this CSS:

```
.text1.transparent {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```